# Changing font-family in wordpress overriding WPBakery Page builder

Tags: css, wordpress, typography

Can someone help me with changing font-size of the whole website built in WordPress? 
I tried changing font-size in Theme>Appearance>Typography but didn't work. Iam using WPBakery Page builder and my guess is WPBakery is overriding the theme font-size, TinyMCE plugin was also being used before, now I have deactivated it. The problem is the website has too many pages and posts so I can't change it by going to every single page. Is there a way to change it for all pages and posts at once.
I tried using custom CSS in Appearance>Custom CSS but didn't work

```
p { 
font-size:16px; 
}
```

This is the website [IBTA Arabia](https://www.ibta-arabia.com)

Sorry if I am on the wrong forum as I am kinda new here.

Comment: If you don't have access to the actual code to add CSS to, then have a look at the [Simple Custom CSS](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/) plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write in Appearance > Custom CSS like below code:

```
p, p span {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have span inside the p tag so you need to add font-size to span too.

like

```
p, span {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

You might need to use `!important` to overwrite the page builder `CSS`